# Ag-Grid : search Option in Rich select

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid-ng2

How can I search in Rich select? Any options like autosuggestion or typing fist character can be useful. In these cases, will the cursor directly go to that name?

Answer (score 0):

(Can't leave comments) I guess it would be easier to implement custom cell editor with some kind of typeahead.

Comment: Thanks..Can you suggest any reference link where this is implemented?